# How do I select only 1 record per user id using ROW_NUMBER without a subquery?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

My current method of de-duping is really dumb.

```
select col1, col2 ... col500 from 
(select col1, col2 ... col500, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY uid) as row_num)
where row_num=1;
```

Is there a way to do this without a subquery? Select distinct is not an option as there can be small variations in the columns which are not significant for this output.

Comment: What is the problem with the subquery? That looks like a perfect query to me.

Comment: Window functions are rendered after the query, in your example, first it runs the `SELECT col1,col2... FROM ...` then it runs the Window Function row_number **OVER** the results of the query. That's why you use a subquery to get duplicates. It's not dumb, it's what it is, and is one of the best ways to solve this kind of query. Otherwise, you would have to write a PL for this.

Comment: Oh well. I have so many columns that repeating them twice looks clumsy. Thanks for your feedback Juan, Dan

Comment: why not leave it with a star and row_number function and have it in the final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres `distinct on ()` is typically faster then the equivalent solution using a window function and also doesn't require a sub-query:

```
select distinct on (uuid) *
from the_table
order by something
```

You **have** to supply an order by (which is something you should have done with `row_number()` as well) to get stable results - otherwise the chosen row is "random".

---

The above is true for Postgres. You also tagged your question with `amazon-redshift` - I have no idea if Redshift (which is in fact a very different DBMS) supports the same thing nor if it is as efficient.